# CSS understanding masking shapes behind portions of an SVG?

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve this effect I drew up in my design tool to practice CSS, but realizing I'm lacking the terminology to search for understanding how the clipping should work here.

[My sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4ajo.png)

Notice the ellipse is in front of the image to start, but the back of the ellipse is behind the image. I assume some sort of masking, but what would this even be called? I see with animation keyframes people can do this with objects by dynamically modifying the z-index, but this is more static.

```html
<div>
  <div className="ellipse"/>
  <div className="globe/>
      // svg
</div>
```

Above is the sort of structure I'm dealing with.

I'm looking to ultimately mask the back portion of the ellipse behind the image. My thinking is I actually create an illusion by using 2 different ellipse with varying z-index, but that still doesn't really help me since I need like a clipped ellipse?

## Edit:

I think I solved this, but open to more efficient methods:

```css
.ellipse {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 80%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 340px;
}

.ellipse-mid {
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 200%;
  height: 145px;
  margin-top: 315px;
  width: calc(100% + 240px);
  margin-left: -120px;
  margin-right: -120px;
}

.ellipse-large {
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 200%;
  height: 195px;
  margin-top: 290px;
  width: calc(100% + 340px);
  margin-left: -180px;
  margin-right: -180px;
}

.globe {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
}

.globe-top {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 60%, 0 50%);
}

.globe-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(0 45%, 100% 59%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Where I use 2 SVGs and clip them top and bottom 50%

```
        <div className="globe">
          <div className="ellipse" />
          <div className="ellipse ellipse-mid" />
          <div className="ellipse ellipse-large" />
          <img src="/globe.svg" className="globe-top" />
          <img src="/globe.svg" className="globe-bottom" />
        </div>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5yLk.png)